# How do we show $\operatorname E\left[X_\tau\mid\tau=t\right]=\operatorname E\left[X_t\mid\tau=t\right]$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-probability, stopping-times

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space;
- $(X_t)_{t\in[0,\:\infty]}$ be a real-valued process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$;
- $\tau$ be an $[0,\infty]$-valued random variable on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$.

> Now let $$\varphi(t):=\operatorname E\left[X_\tau\mid\tau=t\right]\;\;\;\text{for }t\in[0,\infty].$$ How can we prove the intuitively trivial claim $$\varphi(t)=\operatorname E\left[X_t\mid\tau=t\right]\tag1$$ for all $t\in[0,\infty]$?

By definition, $\varphi$ is the function from the factorization lemma; i.e. it is the Borel measurable function $[0,\infty]\to\mathbb R$ with $\varphi\circ\tau=\operatorname E[X_\tau\mid\tau]$. Now, let $$\tilde\varphi(t):=\operatorname E\left[X_t\mid\tau=t\right]\;\;\;\text{for }t\in[0,\infty].$$

Now, by the local property of the conditional expectation and from noting that $$X_\tau=X_t\;\;\;\text{on }\{\tau=t\}\tag2,$$ we obtain $$\varphi(t)=\varphi(\tau)=\operatorname E[X_\tau\mid\tau]=\operatorname E[X_t\mid\tau]=\tilde\varphi(\tau)=\tilde\varphi(t)\tag3$$ almost surely on $\{\tau=t\}$ for all $t\in[0,\infty]$. But is this really enough to conclude?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot conclude anything in general if $P[\tau=t] = 0$ since the probability $P[\cdot|\tau=t]$ are not well-defined. Moreover, using regular version of conditional probability does not solve the problem.

A counterexample. Let $\tau$ be a random time with diffuse law and set $X_t=1_{[\tau=t]}$ for all $t \ge 0$. Since $X_t$ is null with probability $1$, $E[X_t|\sigma(\tau)] = 0$ almost surely, i.e. $E[X_t|\tau=s] = 0$ for almost  (for the law of $\tau$) every $s$. Yet, $X_\tau=1$ so $E[X_\tau|\sigma(\tau)] = 1$ almost surely, i.e. $E[X_\tau|\tau=s] = 1$ for almost  (for the law of $\tau$) every $s$. Hence, the most natural choices when $s=t$ are $E[X_t|\tau=t] = 0$ and $E[X_\tau|\tau=t] = 1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can we show something, when $\operatorname P[\tau=t\right]\ne0$? To give some context, please take note of [my other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4482416/47771).

Comment: @Oxbadf00d Yes. If two integrable random variable $U$ and $V$ coincide almost surely on an event $A$ with strictly positive probability, then $U1_A=V1_A$ almost surely. Taking expectations and dividing by $P(A)$ gives $E[U|A]=E[V|A]$.

Comment: I guess this is not useful in the application that I've got in mind. I basically intend to write $\operatorname E[X_\tau]=\int\operatorname P\left[\tau\in{\rm d}t\right]\operatorname E[X_\tau\mid\tau=t]$. I guess we cannot conclude $\operatorname E[X_\tau]=\int\operatorname P\left[\tau\in{\rm d}t\right]\operatorname E[X_t\mid\tau=t]$, unless $\tau(\Omega)$ is countable, since it could be the case that $\operatorname P[\tau=t]=0$ for all $t\in[0,\infty]$, but $\tau\not\equiv0$. Right?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Yes.

Comment: Wait a second, what if we know that $X_\tau$ is $\sigma(\tau)$-measurable? In that case, $\operatorname E[X_\tau\mid\tau]=X_\tau$ and hence we trivially should have $\operatorname E[X_\tau\mid\tau=t]=X_t$ for all $t\in[0,\infty]$. Do you agree?

Comment: @0xbadf00d No. Look at my counter-example, where $X_\tau=1$ is $\sigma(\tau)$-measurable.

Comment: Sorry, what I wrote doesn't even make sense, since the left-hand side is deterministic, while the right-hand side is random. I'm stilling trying to find a solution for the other question; did you take a look?

Comment: Maybe we need some kind of independence between $\tau$ and $X_t$ on $\{t\ge\tau\}$ ...

Comment: @0xbadf00d I saw only one question. What is the other one?

Comment: I meant this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4482416/47771.