# Can we show $\frac1t\operatorname E\left[f(X_{\tau-});t\ge\tau\right]\xrightarrow{t\to0+}\operatorname E\left[c(X_0)f(X_0)\right]$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space;
- $E$ be a topological space;
- $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ be an $E$-valued right-continuous process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$;
- $c:E\to[0,\infty)$ be locally bounded and Borel measurable;
- $$M_t:=\exp\left(-\int_0^tc(X_s)\:{\rm d}s\right)\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0$$ and $$M_\infty:=0;$$
- $$\tau:=\inf\left\{t\ge0:\int_0^tc(X_s)\:{\rm d}s\ge\xi\right\}$$ for some exponentialy distributed (with parameer $1$) random variable $\xi$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ independent of $X$.

Let $\alpha_\omega$ denote the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure on $\mathcal B([0,\infty])$ induced by the right-continuous nondecreasing function $M(\omega)$ for $\omega\in\Omega$.

We can easily show that $$\operatorname P\left[\tau>t\right]=\operatorname E\left[M_t\right]\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0\tag1$$ and hence $$\operatorname P\left[\tau\in B\right]=\operatorname E\left[\alpha(B)\right]\;\;\;\text{for all }B\in\mathcal B([0,\infty])\tag2,$$ where $\alpha(\omega,B):=\alpha_\omega(B)$ for $\omega\in\Omega$ and $\alpha(B):=\alpha(\;\cdot\;,B)$ for $B\in\mathcal B([0,\infty]$.

Let $$\mathcal F_{\tau-}:=\sigma(\{A\cap\{t<\tau\}:A\in\mathcal F_t\text{ and }t\ge0\}).$$

> Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be bounded and Borel measurable. How can we prove that $$\frac1t\operatorname E\left[f(X_{\tau-});t\ge\tau\right]\xrightarrow{t\to0+}\operatorname E\left[c(X_0)f(X_0)\right]\tag3$$ (at least under suitable further assumptions on $f$)?

I've tried to write \begin{equation}\begin{split}\operatorname E\left[f(X_{\tau-});t\ge\tau\right]&=\int\operatorname P\left[\tau\in{\rm d}s\right]\operatorname E\left[f(X_{\tau-});t\ge\tau\mid\tau=s\right]\\&=\operatorname E\left[\int_{[0,\:t]}\operatorname E\left[f(X_{\tau-});t\ge\tau\mid\tau=s\right]\:{\rm d}(-M_s)\right]\\&=\operatorname E\left[\int_0^t\operatorname E\left[f(X_{\tau-});t\ge\tau\mid\tau=s\right]\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}s}M_s\:{\rm d}s\right]\end{split}\tag4\end{equation}

Comment: What are the properties of $f$?

Comment: @DieterKadelka Sorry, I've forgotten to add that. $f$ is bounded and Borel measurable; but most probably we need to assume more.

Comment: Maybe we need some kind of independence between $\tau$ and $X_{s\in[0,\:t]}$ on $\{t\ge\tau\}$ ......

Comment: Do you mind adding the proof for $$\operatorname P\left[\tau>t\right]=\operatorname E\left[M_t\right] ?$$

Comment: Hello? I'm curious. Btw, what book is this from?

Comment: @Diger It is not from a particular book. Just note that $$\tau>t\Leftrightarrow\int_0^tc(X_s)\:{\rm d}s<\xi\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0$$ and hence the claim follows (since $X$ is independent of $\xi$ and $\xi\sim\operatorname{Exp}(1)$).